# how to pass model to partialview in umbraco?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, umbraco

I want to pass a object as model to a partial view in umbraco. there is two function **@Html.Partial()** and **@Html.Partial()** which have 4 override method listed below :

```
@Html.Partial(string partialName)
@Html.Partial(string partialName, Object object)
@Html.Partial(string partialName, Object object, ViewDataDictionary dic)
@Html.Partial(string partialName, ViewDataDictionary dic)
```

and :

```
@Html.RenderPartial(string partialName)
@Html.RenderPartial(string partialName, Object object)
@Html.RenderPartial(string partialName, Object object, ViewDataDictionary dic)
@Html.RenderPartial(string partialName, ViewDataDictionary dic)
```

I try to use **@Html.RenderPartial(string partialName, Object object)** and 
@Html.Partial(string partialName, Object object) but i an getting this Exception:

> Cannot bind source type <>f__AnonymousType0`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] to model type Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel.

I search a lot in google to an example of using these methods but i cannot find any thing. so there are two question:

1. What is different between Partial and RenderPartial method?
2. How can I pass data to partialview from page razor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution. my PartialView was inherited from :

> Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage

now i change its inheritance to :

> @inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage`<MyModel>`

and then I can add mymodel object to RenderPartial() Method.